# Dart memory leaks and garbage collection

Tags: memory-leaks, garbage-collection, dart

I understand that currently Dart doesn't have an explicit way to remove objects from memory and that objects that are no longer referenced anywhere are removed automatically.

Yet I've been running some benchmarking. Here's the code:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';

var components = [];
var times_to_run = 10;

class MockComponent {

  Element element = new Element.html('<table></table>');

  remove() {
    element.remove();
    element = null;
  }

}

createAndRemoveComponents(t) {

  var n = 50000; // number of objects to create and delete in this run

  print("***Run #${times_to_run}");
  print("creating $n objects...");
  for(var i=0; i < n; i++) {
    components.add(new MockComponent());
  }
  print("...done");


  print("removing $n objects...");
  while(components.length > 0) {
    components.removeAt(0).remove();
  }
  print("...done");

  times_to_run -= 1;

  if(times_to_run <= 0) {
    components = null;
    t.cancel();
  }

}

void main() {
  new Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 10), createAndRemoveComponents);
}
```

I made a video of this code running, so please take a look and see for yourself that memory actually leaks: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVD8Npvc9vQ

Comment: Could you please provide the entire code (loop)
You don't even add the element, why remove (should not leak anyway)
Does the GC have air to breath while your loop runs to do his work?
Some Timer.run(() => ...) or similar.

Comment: Yeah, I intentionally create an element when declaring the variable `element`, but don't really add it to the DOM, so as to isolate the case to my classes and code only. I also tried to run this with the timer interval of 10 secs, looks like it's the same story. I'm gonna investigate a bit more and post an update.

Comment: Don't know if this works with Dart/Dartium https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling

Comment: Please post the loop code too and some more information about the amount of memory consumed. Eventually a screenshot of the devtools. You could also try what I suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645310 (weird but worked in this case)

Comment: Thanks, this profiler works in Dartium, I'm gonna try it and see what's going on. I'll post the updates.

Comment: @gunter-zochbauer I updated the code and also posted a video of this code running in Dartium. I tried the tool you suggested, but for now I'm still not sure how to use it, since it doesn't really display Dart objects, only JS-ones.

Comment: @snitko Does the same thing happen when you run this after compiling to JS in a regular browser?

Comment: @steven-roose haven't tried it. Will do it and will update the post then.

Comment: Just as a sidenote: From what I have experienced, there is also a difference if code is run in Dartium or in some other browser via Dart2JS. On a few occasions, I have seen memory leaks in Dartium VM resulting in crashes that aren't present in the compiled JS code.

Comment: Could be the same or at least a similar issue: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=9405

Comment: @dennis-kaselow the description is very similar to what I experience.

Comment: I could reproduce it on Linux. I think that it's more important how transpiled JavaScript behaves. In Dartium this should probably be run with Development tools closed and ideally not started from Darteditor but opened from another web server or from a file URI to exclude Darteditor's debug connection from the equation.

Comment: @gunter-zochbauer just to clarify, this was run without using Dart editor.

Comment: I ran the same code as compiled Javascript in Chrome, memory WASN'T leaking at all.